# A criterion for complete lattice.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, examples-counterexamples, lattice-orders

Is there an infinite partially ordered set $(X,\le)$, in which for each $A\subseteq X$, either $\inf A$ or $\sup A$ exists but for some $A\subseteq X$ either $\inf A$ or $\sup A$ does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.   Take the order type $\omega$.  (To be clear:  Here $\emptyset$ has a supremum but not an infimum, and the whole set has an infimum but not a supremum.)